# laptop recommendation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community,

I am evaluating the purchase of a laptop to run ROS (fuerte or groovy) under Ubuntu 12.04. The most important requirement is that it should be able to handle data from at least 2 RGB-D sensors (Kinect and alike, I should be careful with USB 3.0 issues and all that).

Any recommendation?
Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52679/laptop-recommendation/) by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5625 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-01-17**:
Openni driver seems work not fine with ubuntu 12.04. I met several problem with that. Especially USB 3.0 couldn't work. I can't find any way work with USB3.0 in my laptop. I only share my experience not the fact that every computer have the same error.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-01-17**:
Hi sam! Thanks for sharing!! Yeah, I am also having trouble on the desktop PC with multiple openni devices with USB 3.0. Everything works fine if I plug them to USB 2.0. Apparently you need to patch kernels lower than 3.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use a SYSTEM 76 serval laptop with 2 RGB-D sensors. It works quite well.

---

Originally posted by [Akin](https://answers.ros.org/users/230/akin/) with karma: 186 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-01-17**:
Hi Akin! Thanks for your quick reply! Did you had any issue with the RGB-D sensors and the USB 3.0 ports? As far as I know, you need to patch the kernel if your version is lower than 3.4.1. Thanks!

**Comment by [Akin](https://answers.ros.org/users/230/akin/) on 2013-01-17**:
The laptop that I mentioned has only USB 2.0 ports. But I had had unsuccessful attempts to make kinect work with USB 3.0. I would strongly recommend a laptop where you can select to use USB3's in USB2 mode in BIOS. I know that Lenovos has that option. I think Dell laptops too.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-01-17**:
Uhhh I didn't know you could set USB2 mode, that is great news! I'll research about it! Thanks Akin :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure it has an nvidia graphics card, but avoid nvidia optimus (graphics card + intel on-chip graphics), as the latter is not well-supported under linux. Unless there is a BIOS or hardware switch to turn it off.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-02-08**:
I have found the NVidia Optimus system works great, thanks to the Bumblebee Linux driver. I would say don't get ~any~ NVidia card, make sure it's a dedicated gaming card. Avoid workstation-level cards like the NVidia Quadro series, and avoid cards that get their memory by sharing the RAM.